# Reporting on Tasks

Tags: formula, reporting, account, tasks, custom

I am trying to display only Accounts that do not have tasks with the word "review" in the subject. I am unable to do this correctly with the following filters:
[image]
The report results will display: Accounts that have "review" in the task subject if there is more than 1 task associated with the account which is incorrect.

However if there is only 1 task associated with the account and it does contain "review" in the subject the account is not displayed in the results which is correct, the problem seems to be with multiple tasks associated with accounts. Any help much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the opposite logic -- Accounts without Activities that contain the word "review".  When you have a "with" filter, the logic applies to every child record independently, so if **at least one** child record meets the criteria, then the parent is included.

Comment: thanks for this David it worked :)